# Power Shell List Item Copy

Tags: list, powershell

I am trying to copy a list from one web app to another web application .All the list items are copying fine except for Contact Details (which is  column of type person).This column is showing empty . Can anyone suggest me how to make this work

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use EnsureUser and pass AccountID for target list item.

For example,

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser =    $spWeb.EnsureUser("domain\username")
 $spListItem[$newSMTName] =  $spuser
 $spListItem.Update()